"Illegal Offset Type" exception on "save()" method in Laravel
I've this simple application built with Laravel and Eloquent, that should connect to a localhost phpmyAdmin Database.
I've got this method:
public function clickOrderPlateClient($id_client, $id_plate){
        $order = Order::where('id_client', $id_client)
            ->where('id_plate', $id_plate)
            ->first();

        $order->qt = ($order->qt) + 1;
        $order->save();
    }

which should increment by 1 the attribute "qt" in my table "orders" (described by the class Order) in the record corresponding to the given client which has ordered the given dish.
But I'm always getting an "Illegal offset type" error corresponding to the $order->save(); row.
error
this is my Order class:
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Order extends Model
{
    protected $table ='orders';
    protected $primaryKey = ['id_client','id_plate'];
    public $timestamps = false;
    public $incrementing = false;

    public function getClient(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Client','id_client');
    }

    public function getPlate(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Plates','id_plate');
    }
}



Is creating new Order working fine?

yes, absolutely, with all the related foreign keys. That works perfectly fine

Does this answer your question? Illegal offset type on save a one to many relationship in laravel

@kopz maybe i just figured out what the problem is....
I made a mistake in the ER model during the db project... It's not a 1-n, but it's a n-n... so that class shouldn't exist, because it will be already described by the provided methods in Eloquent (belongsToMany). In fact that's why (i just figured out) this is the only class to have a composite primary key.
Should I delete the class, and will it work?

You can not use two primary keys in the model.
Try to work with "composite key"
Solution 1:
With library:
composer command to install the library
composer require thiagoprz/eloquent-composite-key

Model code:
<?php
namespace App\Models;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Thiagoprz\EloquentCompositeKey\HasCompositePrimaryKey;
class Order extends Model
{
    use HasCompositePrimaryKey;
    protected $table ='orders';
    protected $primaryKey = ['id_client','id_plate'];
    public $timestamps = false;
    public $incrementing = false;
    public function getClient(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Client','id_client');
    }
    public function getPlate(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Plates','id_plate');
    }
}

For reference check here: Laravel: working with Composite Keys
Solution 2:
Without installing any library:
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Order extends Model
{
    protected $table ='orders';
    protected $primaryKey = 'composite_key';
    public $timestamps = false;
    public $incrementing = false;

    public function getClient(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Client', 'id_client');
    }

    public function getPlate(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Plates', 'id_plate');
    }

    // Define the composite key attribute
    public function getCompositeKeyAttribute()
    {
        return $this->id_client . '-' . $this->id_plate;
    }
}


what do you mean by "you can not two primary keys in the model"?

Added the word 'use' for clarity: 'You can not use two primary keys in the model.'
